# Interesting application of E-M algorithm

Tags: estimation, expected-value, inference, expectation-maximization

Suppose the following dataset:

```
[3 4 3 4 6 12 12 7 8 9]
[2 5 3 4 12 2 2 10 7 6]
[3 4 3 4 5 11 10 7 8 9]
```

These numbers are totally random. So this dataset, depicts three (3) players going to a casino with 10 tables, where they play a dice game. Each player throws his/her own dice (that might be biased) and then the player also throws table's dice (that might be also biased) and then we observe the sum and then he/she moves on to the next table. So, the first row of the matrix , that is, `[3 4 3 4 6 12 12 7 8 9]` means: player 1, visited 10 tables, with sum outcomes `3 4 3 4 6 12 12 7 8 9` from each table.

I would like to estimate the dice parameters. For example if all the dice are fair I would expect to get a uniform distribution for dice parameters right?

I am puzzled, 1) whether is this possible to do with an E-M approach 2) If it is possible, how big is my parameter space? do i have to find like 6+6 parameters? What is the correct approach for this?

Comment: Does column index correspond to the table?  E.g. first entry in each row is for table #1, for which you have three observations in total, one for each player?

Comment: Also feels like you have to determine how to parameterize the notion of a "biased" die - at its most extreme that's 5 parameters per die, for 3 dice that belong to the players and the 10 dice that belong to the tables.  5 * 13 = 65 parameters, more than your number of observations in that case.

Comment: @MichaelOberst Theoretically, I can generate a big amount of observations so that wouldn't be a problem. My above vectors were random for the sake of the example. I don't quite understand why you said 5 parameters instead of 6. A dice has 6 faces as far as i know.

Comment: Just my intuition - once you know the probability of 5 of the numbers coming up, then the probability of the 6th is fixed (1- the rest)

Comment: It is possible to use EM to derive the probability vectors for all of the dice. By breaking the sum $X_i+Y_i$ into $X_i$ and $Y_i$ as latent variables. However, without additional assumptions on the bias in the dice, this maximum likelihood estimator cannot be much precise.